# Styling alternating lines in atom editor

Tags: css, atom-editor

I was looking through the atom-editor settings and thought I would make a simple change to show a different colour for alternating lines so I could see what was happening when a line wrapped.

It looks like the editor does not display the lines in order though:

[image: Sample of line highlight issue in atom editor]

As you can see on line 26 I am trying to get each even line to have a different background colour but line 12, 13, and 14 are all highlighted.

Looking at the developer tools (`Command-option-i` on Mac) shows that the lines are stored out of order in the document so they do alternate but that is not how they highlight on screen.

Is there a way to consistently make alternating lines highlight?

**Edit:**

I have also tried adding the style to the row numbers:

```
.editor .line[data-screen-row]:nth-child(2n) {
  background-color:red;
}
```

This also seems to have issues, also I noticed that when the lines wrap they are given a new line number.

Comment: I was also wondering if anyone could explain why the documents are stored in such a strange way?

Comment: I have added an issue on the atom issue page https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/4829

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you're asking for is possible the way Atom is currently architected. To my understanding, the lines are placed in the DOM in whatever order is most expedient at the time of their insertion/modification and then positioned on the screen using absolute positioning as you can see in the `style` attribute of each `div`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the prettiest solution, but would do the trick for you:

```
atom-text-editor::shadow .line[data-screen-row$="0"],
atom-text-editor::shadow .line[data-screen-row$="2"],
atom-text-editor::shadow .line[data-screen-row$="4"],
atom-text-editor::shadow .line[data-screen-row$="6"],
atom-text-editor::shadow .line[data-screen-row$="8"] {
  background-color: #292929;
}
```